# Add selected columns of a file as values to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I am analyzing a small corpus, and want to create a dictionary based on 500k text files.

These text files consist of numbered lines which are tab-separated columns with some strings (or numbers), i.e.:

```
1    string1    string2    string3    # ...and so on, but I only need columns 2-4
2    string1    string2    string3    # ...and so on...
3    string1    string2    string3    # ...and so on...
4    string1    string2    string3    # ...and so on...
# ...and so on...
```

I am only simplifying it, these words not necessarily are the same in every line, but they do repeat over the whole corpus.

I want to create a dictionary with second column (with "string1") as a key and 3rd and 4th columns as values for that key, but also with a sum of all repetitions of a specific key within that corpus.

Should be something like this:

```
my_dict = {
    "string1": [99, "string2", "string3"],
    "string1": [51, "string2", "string3"],
    # ...and so on...
}
```

So, "string1" stands for tokens, number is a counter for these tokens, "string2" stands for lemma, "string3" stands for category (some of them need to be omitted, as in the code below).

I've managed (with a big help of stackoverflow) to write-copy some code:

```
import os
import re
import operator

test_paths = ["path1", "path2", "path3"]
cat_to_omit = ["CAT1", "CAT2"]
tokens = {}

for path in test_paths:
    dirs = os.listdir(path)
    for file in dirs:
        file_path = path + file
        with open(file_path) as f:
            for line in f:
                if re.match(r"^\d+.*", line): #selecting only lines starting with numbers, because some of them don't, and I don't need these
                    check = line.split()[3]
                    if check not in cat_to_omit: #omitting some categories that I don't need
                        token_lst = line.lower().split()[1]
                        for token in token_lst.split():
                            tokens[token] = tokens.get(token, 0) + 1
print(tokens)
```

Now I am only getting, which is obvious, "string1" (which is a token) as a key + counter for this token's occurences within my corpus as a value. How can I add a list of 3 values for each key (token):
1. counter, which I already have as the only value for each key,
2. lemma, which should be taken from column 3 ("string2"),
3. category, which should be taken from column 4 ("string3").

It seems I just don't understand, how to turn my "key: value" dictionary into a "key: 3 values" one.

Comment: You still want `key: value` (that's the only way to do it). Your `value` is just going to be a list like `[99, "string2", "string3"]`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes. So, can I change my dictionary's structure straight in the code above, also saving this `tokens[token] = tokens.get(token, 0) + 1` counter formula? And, simultaneously, adding other values with the same idea of token_lst -> `for token in token_lst:` and so on..?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what `token_lst` is, but somewhere, you'd have something to the effect of `token['string1'] = [counter, 'string2', 'string3']`

Comment: `token_lst` is a list of 2nd-column strings for each line of a file/files I load with `test_paths` (the keys in my dictionaty). I want to do the same with 3rd-column strings as `lemmas` and 4th-column strings as `categories` to get `tokens = {"token": counter, "lemmas", "categories"]`.

Comment: Ofc, I ment: tokens = {"token": [counter, "lemmas", "categories"]}.